# When is a good time use EAV?

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a networking site to allow manufacturers to network with Producers. My boss wants other organizations to be able to upload excel files to the website of their products and have it stored in the database. Each product that people enter could have their own host of properties. Maybe the company could somehow control the attributes they want to display on said networking site. That said this seems like a time where I might end up with near inifinite amount of attributes and EAV seems like it makes alot of sense for this type of task.

I went here to see my different options:
[How to design a product table for many kinds of product where each product has many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695752/how-to-design-a-product-table-for-many-kinds-of-product-where-each-product-has-m)

[Is this a good case to use EAV or no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537241/is-this-a-good-case-to-use-eav-or-no)
 and saw that there were these questions

Do you have a lot of product types ?

Do you need to handle "variants" of the products ?

Do you intend to add entirely new types of products ?

and the answer for all of them in my mind is yes SO I think this is a good time to use eav but I'm not sure because I know some people think EAV IS the the enemy. I also have no experience using a nosql database and maybe that is the direction I should think about going.  if it matters at all im doing the back end with asp.net visual studio as of right now.

But on a sidenote I feel like this is a bad task to give a singular intern (still in college) to make a networking site this big when you are a small manufacturing company with no cs division... debating quitting.

regardless does anyone have any advice as to if I should stick with MySQL and try eav vs one of the other options from the first link.

Comment: as of right now I'm leaning toward option 2 of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce?rq=1